# How do I draw a flipped subset of a bitmap on Android?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, flip, drawbitmap

I'm using drawBitmap(Bitmap image, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint); to draw a portion of an image. Is there a way to do this and also flip the image?

Comment: Yes, image is a matrix, so assuem its 4x4 pixel image. so extract block wise pixel. Once you get a portion of image i think then you can apply any matrix transformation on image like rotateX().

Comment: I guess I'm trying to do this without another temporary bitmap. I thought maybe if I flip the left and right of the dst Rect that it would work, but nothing is appearing. My guess is that it is being back face culled (I'm assuming they are using OpenGL ES to do their rendering). If someone can confirm and also maybe know a way to disable this?

Comment: Ok regarding 1st approach, r u invalidating the view. Your approach is equally good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, image is a matrix, so assuem its 4x4 pixel image. so extract block wise pixel. Once you get a portion of image i think then you can apply any matrix transformation on image like rotateX().